# 'HTTPMethod' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context?

Tags: swift, alamofire

> Can anyone help with this issue? I am using swift 5 and Xcode 10.3
>
> The code below was created with purpose of avoiding duplicating code.
>   So I created new function to request server with passing parameters
>   below.

```
func requestServer(_ method: HTTPMethod,_ path: String,_ params: [String: Any]?,_ encoding:
    ParameterEncoding,_ completionHandler: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {

    let url = baseURL?.appendingPathComponent(path)

    refreshTokenIfNeed {

        AF.request(url!, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: encoding, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let jsonData = JSON(value)
                completionHandler(jsonData)
                break


            case .failure:
                completionHandler(nil)
                break

            }
        }
    }

}

// API - Getting Restaurant list
func getRestaurant(completionHandler: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {

    let path = "api/customer/restaurants"
    requestServer(.get, path, nil, URLEncoding(), completionHandler)


}

// API - Getting list of Meal for Restaurants
func getMeals(restauranId: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {

    let path = "api/customer/meals/\(RestaurantId)"
    requestServer(.get, path, nil, URLEncoding(), completionHandler)
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring? Have you imported Alamofire?

Also, you should have external labels in your `requestServer` method, otherwise your code is rather unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

use this before u call a function

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and consider [providing some explanations along with your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23960532)

Comment: You need to call the httpmethod as per the url type method GET 0r POST

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error by adding Alamofire prior to HTTPMethod -> `func requestServer(_ method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod,_ path: String,_ params: [String: Any]?,_ encoding:
        ParameterEncoding,_ completionHandler: @escaping (JSON) -> Void)`

but now I have an issue with code below stating the following: 'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'JSON'

' AF.request(url!, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: encoding, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in

```
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let jsonData = JSON(value)
                completionHandler(jsonData)
                break


            case .failure:
                completionHandler(nil)     <------ this is a trigger
                break

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I worked around that by appliying nil! which allowed me bypass the error but inside the app I am not able to logout and get the following error:

**2019-09-04 08:13:22.518630-0400 DeliveryMobile[980:52117] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C12.2:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-09-04 08:13:22.530669-0400 DeliveryMobile[980:52117] TIC Read Status [12:0x60000031eac0]: 1:57
2019-09-04 08:13:25.302686-0400 DeliveryMobile[980:52131] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C13.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-09-04 08:13:25.305162-0400 DeliveryMobile[980:52131] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C13.2:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-09-04 08:13:25.325531-0400 DeliveryMobile[980:52992] TIC Read Status [13:0x60000031eac0]: 1:57
2019-09-04 08:13:34.886240-0400 DeliveryMobile[980:52558] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C14.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR**